# Generic async Retry with Timeout function in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have hundreds of calls to various external API's that I want to wrap in a generic async function that is capable of doing retries and handling timeouts.

Basically, I think I need to implement something like this function call:

```
await Retry(()=>someFunctionAsync(doWorkParams, new CancellationToken()), retryCount, timeout);
```

How do I define such Retry function?  Also, how do I call this function from Sync code, as a ton of my calls are housed in the sync methods?

Answer (score 12):

Don't reinvent the wheel. [Just use Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) which supports exactly the scenario you're talking about as well as all kinds of scenarios for retry and advanced patterns like circuit breaker.

Here's an async example from their docs:

```
await Policy
  .Handle<SqlException>(ex => ex.Number == 1205)
  .Or<ArgumentException>(ex => ex.ParamName == "example")
  .RetryAsync()
  .ExecuteAsync(() => DoSomethingAsync());
```

Answer (score 10):

> How do I define such Retry function?

1. Install [`Polly`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).
2. Define a policy and use it.
3. Profit.

Something like this should work:

```
static async Task RetryAsync(Func<CancellationToken, Task> func, int retryCount, TimeSpan timeout)
{
  using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout))
  {
    var policy = Policy.Handle<Exception>(ex => !(ex is OperationCanceledException))
        .RetryAsync(retryCount);
    await policy.ExecuteAsync(() => func(cts.Token)).ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
}
```

> Also, how do I call this function from Sync code, as a ton of my calls are housed in the sync methods?

That's a totally different question. Blocking on asynchronous code always has pitfalls. There is no solution that works for any arbitrary `Func<Task>`. See my [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx) for a variety of hacks you can try, if you **must** do this. It would be better, though, to keep asynchronous code asynchronous, and synchronous code synchronous.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for sounding stupid.. but I dont see how your example will properly cancel my long-running async calls, like web requests.  Does it automatically handle cancellation tokens to the func() if that func() supports them?

Comment: If you need to cancel them, you can pass a `CancellationToken` in yourself: `await RetryAsync(() => DoSomethingAsync(token), 5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));`

Comment: Sorry, I didnt explain correctly., I meant that if the method times out and Polly decides to cancel it, how will it do that without cancellation token?  I dont need to cancel methods from outside, however, I need them cancelled properly when Timeout is reached.

Comment: Ah, I assumed that parameter was the time to wait between retries. See my edit for how to do timeout-based cancellation.

Answer (score 4):

If you are still curious about how to do it without Policy it would be something like this:

```
/// Untested code
static class Retry
{
    public static async Task<T> Run<T>(Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> function, int retries, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Exception error = null;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
                return await function(cancellation.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                error = ex;
            }

            retries--;
        }
        while (retries > 0);

        throw error;
    }

    public static async Task<T> Run<T>(Func<Task<T>> function, int retries, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Exception error = null;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout);
                var resultTask = function();

                await Task.WhenAny(resultTask, timeoutTask).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (resultTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                    return resultTask.Result;
                else
                    error = new TimeoutException();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                error = ex;
            }

            retries--;
        }
        while (retries > 0);

        throw error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you throw the error only when it is not null. Nice try but point with Polly is the level features rolled up in the Fluent Syntax

Comment: If it gets to the `throw`, `error` is not null. It needs to replace the `while` with a `do/while` to be correct though.

Comment: The question is not about Polly, it is about how to do a retry function. Although I recognize Polly's value, it is interesting to know how to do it by hand as well :)